# What happens if the input high and input low of Buf2 become the same?

Tags: digital-logic

[image]

What happens if the \$V_{IH}\$ is equal to \$V_{IL}\$?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, same as what ? Usually there is a threshold and always a gap between high and low, it's called a Schmidt trigger, it is to avoid unstable states.

Comment: The input characteristics are a function of the device design and operating voltage and are not independently changeable. They can't be the same.

Comment: Sorry I'm not very clear about the question. I got this question for my assignment about noise margin, however I couldn't find any explanation online on what will happen if the input high and input low are the same. I understand they can't be the same.

Comment: @Xon Can you quote the text from your assignment? Maybe that text will make more sense than what you have deciphered from it and put up here on this site. Seeing as nothing you've said makes any sense.

Comment: @HarrySvensson The assignment consists of 2 questions. 1st question being, "For the inverter chain above, calculate the noise margin high and noise margin low". For the 1st question I can answer it. And for the 2nd question is "What happens if input high and input low of the Buf2 become the same? Explain.". That's the question I got for my assignment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are asking about differences in the definitions of the high and low for output and input.

The point is that `Buf2` must have its input signal in its input voltage defined space to operate properly. Your picture shows it will treat low for volages <0.3, and high for voltages >0.7. Thus previous output device `Buf1` must output within these ranges. Rage of [0.3;0.7] will not guarantee `Buf2` to operate properly (whatever fault it may cause to the `Buf2` or its output level).

Thus as drawn on your picture - the circuit will work properly, because `Buf1` outputs low <0.15 which is <0.3, and high >0.8 which is >0.7.

In general you should **always** refer to the datasheet of the devices being connected. Digital logic used to have their output levels defined explicitly so that you can match the standards and see the noise slack you may have.

Answer (score 1):

I will make a wild assumption that the question means *what happens if the threshold voltage for low and high is at a single value* (which is never the case in real):

When the transient pass the threshold, the ouput of Buf 2 might oscillate from GND to VDD depending how fast is your transient.

---

If the question means *the input threshold of Buf 2 becomes the same as Buf 1* (like you change the chip), then it does not matter at all, since the only the first Buf is exposed to your noisy signal, the ouput of the first buffer to the second one should be a clean 0 - VDD signal.

Although it's a lot of guessing, the question is not clear at all.

Comment: Aaaah, reading your first paragraph now makes the entire question more clear. *If* that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens, the gate will still work. As long as \$V_{IH} \ge V_{IL}\$ there is no problem.